# CSS How do i fill this empty space in the box

Tags: css

Guy, Sorry I suck that this

How can i make this all my boxes avoid the spacing made by box 1 so that the box 4 auto adjust on the top

My Fiddle link - http://jsfiddle.net/QKbEk/3/

```
.grp {
width: 140px;
margin: 0px auto;
}

.box {
background: red;
margin: 3px;
float: left;
width: 50px;
height: 50px
}
```

Comment: This sort of problem with layout is common with CSS. You will need to re-think this one and there will be no way around having to use Javascript or jQuery in your solution. There is a popular javascript library for re-arranging containers but, even that library has no examples from what I can tell where heights are adjusted the way that you want: http://isotope.metafizzy.co

Comment: The problem is i can't rethink in this cuz i'm taking out values and complex output from database and i can't edit each value every time this problem shows..i think i've to go with this jQuery

Answer (score 3):

You could change your rule for `.box4` to:

```
.box4 {
    background: red;
    float: left;
    margin: 3px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position:relative;
    top:-25px;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/QKbEk/1/)**

This happens because of the rules applied to floated elements. Specifically, "The outer top of a floating box may not be higher than the outer top of any block or floated box generated by an element earlier in the source document.". However by using positioning you can place the box wherever you need.

Comment: It sounded like OP did not want a fixed height on this box. This seems fine if that is not the case though.

Comment: @Gray - I didn't add a height. Just position and top attributes.

Comment: No i can't do that then i have to apply the position:relative to all my boxes they all are same but for the demo i've made like this\

Comment: I thought the same thing, since the word "auto-adjust" was used

Comment: @Styli - then you have to use JavaScript. Something like masonry.

Comment: **I Said auto-adjust all boxes are same**

Comment: **I've updated the fiddle please have a look now you'll get what i'm trying to reach.**

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="grp">
   <div style="float:left;width:40%">
      <div class="box" style="height: 80px">box 1</div>
      <div class="box">box 4</div>
   </div>
   <div style="float:left;width:40%">
      <div class="box">box 2</div>
      <div class="box">box 3</div>
      <div class="box">box 5</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Joshua Johnson post for masonry design: http://designshack.net/articles/css/masonry/

Comment: You're not getting it.. Box are the value output from the database..so each time the values are different and changed so box size also changes then i am i suppose to do this everytime :P

Comment: I'm talking about this feature in CSS - [Look here](http://masonry.desandro.com/)